# How to express that you "do the work first, and only then write an invoice"?

Tags: expressions

I would like to tell a potential client that there is no need for any prepayment and that he will simply receive an invoice after the work is completed. Is there a way to express this succinctly? In German, you could say "Wir arbeiten auf Rechnung", which translates to "We work on invoice"... but that doesn't sound right.

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Payment due on completion

Comment: Invoice on completion and payment due on receipt.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As BruceMurray said in a comment, "Payment due on completion" is a common phrase to write on a form or contract. Or as I usually see it, "Payment due upon completion."

Another common phrase is, "Payment due on delivery" -- this implies they must pay when you deliver as opposed to, you will deliver and then send them a bill.

If you want a complete sentence, "We will invoice you when the work is complete." If you want to be super clear, you might say, "No deposit or prepayment is necessary. We will invoice (or "bill") you when the work is complete."